# optimizer always full scans table eben though fething only 3 rows

Tags: oracle, performance, database-performance

I have a table foo which was created like this.

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS SELECT * FROM all_objects;

CREATE INDEX foo_I1 ON foo(owner,object_type,status);
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('hr','foo',method_opt=>'FOR ALL COLUMNS size AUTO');
```

I created an index  on 3 columns and firing a query which looks like below.

```
select  * from foo where status='INVALID';
select  * from foo where status='VALID';
```

status='VALID' fetches near about 71000 rows in a table of 71780 rows. it does a full table scan. it's understandable. but in case of status='INVALID' which fetches only 3 rows , it's doing full table scan.  It's also getting A rows and E rows very different.

PLAN: same for both queries.

### SQL_ID  gdhy9j91gu9sm, child number 0

select /*+gather_plan_statistics */ * from foo where status='VALID'

```
Plan hash value: 1245013993

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |      1 |        |     50 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| FOO  |      1 |  71773 |     50 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("STATUS"='VALID')
```

Please explan this behaviour. Database Version: 11.2g oracle.

Comment: Have you tried using a bitmap index for the table? (WARNING: bitmap can be a problem if they table is intensively modified)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A missing histogram is probably causing the full table scan.  Histograms are usually only created if the data is skewed *and* if the column has been used in a relevant predicate.

Sometimes you need to run a query *before* gathering statistics, to let Oracle know that this column is important enough to deserve a histogram.

```
select * from foo where status='INVALID';
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('hr','foo',method_opt=>'FOR ALL COLUMNS size AUTO');
```

Re-run the `SELECT` and now it can use the histogram.  With the histogram Oracle knows that `INVALID` returns a small number of rows, and an index would be useful:

```
explain plan for select * from foo where status='INVALID';
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 1520589999

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |        |     1 |   134 |   217   (0)| 00:00:01|
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| FOO    |     1 |   134 |   217   (0)| 00:00:01|
|*  2 |   INDEX SKIP SCAN                   | FOO_I1 |     1 |       |   216   (0)| 00:00:01|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("STATUS"='INVALID')
       filter("STATUS"='INVALID')
```